сокращения в java
Только начинаю изучать Java и уже столкнулся с тем, что некоторые программисты очень упрощают себе жизнь, написав, к примеру, не System.out.println, а sout + tab.
Где они находят такие сокращения? Как я могу найти такие сокращения?
Насколько я знаю в библиотеках, фреймворках тоже есть эти сокращения. Я думал, что смогу найти это в документации, но у меня как-то не вышло. Возможно, что я просто плохо ищу, поэтому, пожалуйста, дайте мне подробный ответ.

Это настройки IDE, она такое обеспечиват.

а где можно найти все сокращения? Я бы хотел ещё парочку узнать

https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/a0b36pri/teacher/dolgidmi/shortcuts-80.pdf

как вы их находите???

есть ещё полезная штука, как горячие клавиши самой ide. И, например, в IDEA очень полезным в изучении этого оказывается плагин Key Promoter X. Он ненавязчиво (но настойчиво) будет подсказывать "смотри, ты сейчас сделал кучу движений мышкой / руками,  а мог нажать вот такую комбинацию клавиш"

@kami, я искала для NeatBeans такой плагин, но не нашла. Поделитесь ссылкой ?

@Dev18 нет, к сожалению для NetBeans такого не знаю - я в ней не работал. А в Idea - ctrl+alt+s -> plugins->marketplace-> и поиском Key promoter :) , он бесплатен.

В IDEA можно самому таких наделать

Если данные вам ответы оказались полезными, не забудьте принять один из них, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Если вы пользуетесь NeatBeans, то по поиску надо искать shortcuts
Вот список
Ссылка может меняться, поэтому оставлю скрин шот актуальный на сегодня


Eclipse

Можно, использовать plugin-ы, как в комментарии заметил @kami
вот ссылка на plugin Eclipse для работы с Java
А в Idea - ctrl+alt+s -> plugins -> marketplace -> и поиском Key promoter

intellij idea и android studio (да и наверное любая IDE от JetBrains) содержит в себе уже большой набор предустановленных live templates.
С ними можно ознакомиться пройдя по этому пути:

Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)
Editor
Live templates

К примеру, так можно создать свой live template для логирования в android studio.
+ для добавления нового.


Не забудьте добавить определение к какому языку применим этот template.
На уровне кнопок Ok и Cancel есть кнопка Define/Change

Если после настройки набрать mylog + Tab, то будет прописан вызов функции Log.e() куда подтянется автоматически имя класса и имя функции, внутри которой вызывается функция логирования.

В IDE от JetBrains эта фишка называется Live Templates
(ртфм тут: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html)
Посмотреть или кастомизировать их можно в настройках Editor->Live Templates.
